# Laravel 5 recognizes some css and js files as routes

Tags: laravel, assets, laravel-routing

I'm getting mad with this issue.

Basically there are some css and js files which are opened correctly from laravel. But some other js and css files are recognized as routes!

For example: http://localhost:8000/assets/ammap/themes/light.js

[image]

I'm using the following code to access assets from templates:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="{!! asset("assets/ammap/themes/light.js") !!}"></script>
```

Obviously the path is correct and the file exists.

Comment: you sure the asset resides at that location because the .htaccess file should only point to the index.php file if the requested URL is not a file

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. Some css files are being loaded correctly, while others not.

Comment: better install laravel elixir and compile all js and css to two files https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/elixir#installation

Comment: Does it work properly for some other files under the same directory?

Comment: have you altered the .htaccess file in anyway?

Comment: I haven't edited the .htaccess file. It's the original one from Laravel.

 - Yes, it works properly for some other files but not in the same directory.

 - I don't want to pack everything into a single file with Elixir because I need amcharts/ammaps only in a single page.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem.

I'm using OS X and it was a permission issue.

```
chmod -R 0777 public
```

Then set everyone to "Read & Write" into file permissions.

[image]